# How to read the header from a TIdHTTP get

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using `TIdHTTP.Get()` to retrieve records in a JSON format. It will only send me the first 1000 records, and in the header it will have the URL for the next 1000, if there are any.

I can see the header in PostMan, but how do I access it from this call?

```
jsontxt := IdHTTP1.Get(url);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits, the raw response headers can be accessed via the `TIdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders` property.  Many headers also have their own dedicated sub-property in the `TIdHTTP.Response` object.  If your desired header does not, you can use the `RawHeaders.Values[]` property to read it, eg:

```
jsontxt := IdHTTP1.Get(url);
url := IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders.Values['the-next-url-header'];
```

If the header does not exist, `Values[]` will simply return a blank string, eg:

```
url := ...;
repeat
  jsontxt := IdHTTP1.Get(url);
  //...
  url := IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders.Values['the-next-url-header'];
until url = '';
```

Comment: Using Delphi XE6 with Indy 10. Response does not have Headers as a property.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `RawHeaders` instead of `Headers`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks found it after looking through all properties, was going to post it.